# Not defined identifier

Tags: angular

I did forms in Angular 7 and I did `*ngIf` conditions to say user, that he don't insert all data to forms. A tried to use `!` before `*ngIf`, and it is OK for Visual Studio Code, but it has the opposite effect.

This is error:

> [Angular] Identifier 'name' is not defined. '__type' does not contain such a member property messageForm of RegisterComponent

HTML file:

```
<h1>Log in</h1>

<form [formGroup]="messageForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">

  <h5 *ngIf="success">Your form is valid!</h5>

  <label>
    Tvoj nick:
    <input type="text" formControlName="name">
    <div *ngIf="submitted && messageForm.controls.name.errors" class="error">
      <div *ngIf="messageForm.controls.name.errors.required">... aale no, tvoj nick potrebujeme, aby si mal svoj tim</div>
    </div>
  </label>

  <label>
    Email:
    <input type="email" formControlName="email">
    <div *ngIf="submitted && messageForm.controls.email.errors" class="error">
      <div *ngIf="messageForm.controls.email.errors.required">Email je dolezity na zasielanie informacii pre teba</div>
    </div>
  </label>

  <label>
    Tvoje heslo:
    <input type="password" formControlName="password">
    <div *ngIf="submitted && messageForm.controls.password.errors" class="error">
      <div *ngIf="messageForm.controls.password.errors.required">Heslo je zaklad registracie!</div>
    </div>
  </label>

  <input type="submit" value="Zaregistruj sa" class="cta">

</form>
```

TS file:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-register',
  templateUrl: './register.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./register.component.scss']
})
export class RegisterComponent implements OnInit {

  messageForm: FormGroup;
  submitted = false;
  success = false;

  constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.messageForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      name: ['', Validators.required],
      email: ['', Validators.required],
      password: ['', Validators.required]
    });
  }

  onSubmit(){
    this.submitted = true;

    if(this.messageForm.invalid){
      return;
    }

    this.success = true;
  }
}
```

Comment: Maybe I have read through this too quickly, but you may want to take a look at the form validation information on the angular site, most of what you seam to be hand rolling has already been done for you by the angular team, and issues such as required fields should be caught before a submit button is pressed. https://angular.io/guide/form-validation

An example of what I am looking at is the email field where you are doing 2 ng if's, and only checking the required error and not even that it is a valid email and if an error other than required happens, you will show an empty div.

Comment: I donno why, but maybe try use it like this:
this.messageForm.get('name').hasError('required')

Comment: I tried " !! " , and it is work: What do you think about my solution? Is it correct solution in Angular?

Comment: @Lukas who are you talking to? and what do u mean you tried " !! " ??

Comment: @Talg123 to all :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to set validation this way

```
<div *ngIf="submitted && f.name.errors" class="invalid-feedback">
          <div *ngIf="f.name.errors.required">Name is required</div>
</div>
```

In `.ts` file

```
get f() { return this.messageForm.controls; }
```

**Update**

```
<div *ngIf="name?.errors.required">Name is required.</div>


this.messageForm = this.formBuilder.group({
  email: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.email]],
  password: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(3)]]
});
```

[Reference link](http://jasonwatmore.com/post/2018/05/10/angular-6-reactive-forms-validation-example)

**Update email validation issue**

```
<div *ngIf="submitted && f.email.errors" class="invalid-feedback">
    <div *ngIf="f.email.errors.required">Email is required</div>
    <div *ngIf="f.email.errors.email">Email must be a valid email address</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer, but when I do it, it is same end. So "[Angular] Identifier 'name' is not defined. '__type' does not contain such a member". Any idea?

Comment: Thanks :-) But " ?" is not working. I tried " !! " and it is working. What do you think about " !! " ? Is it OK solution?

Comment: Of course, sorry

<div *ngIf="submitted && !!f.password.errors" class="error">
      <div *ngIf="!!f.password.errors.required">Password is required!</div>
    </div>

Comment: All work :-) But I do Validator.minLenght(6) in password, but minLenght is SUM by name, email, password ... I don´t know why :(

   this.messageForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      name: ['', Validators.required],
      email: ['', Validators.required, Validators.email],
      password: ['', Validators.required, Validators.minLength(6)]
    });

Comment: You are missing one ] . password: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(3)]]

Comment: I have add my working formGroup code. Please check it

Comment: Thank you very much :) ... it works! :) and I have one question on you, because you are clever :-) 
I have navigation, but I need navigation bar - something like this: "https://material.angular.io/components/sidenav/overview " ... but when I repair my navigation to Sidenav, my app doesn´t work. Do you know any web page, where I find good explanation to do it?

Comment: Welcome @Lukas Please accept my answer. I'll look in to your new issue.

Comment: OK I create new issue today with navigation problem :-) Thanks

Comment: I have one question about Validators. When user doesn´t insert correct email (for example: 123), my application doesn´t write him about incorrect inserted email. Where can I write it for user?

Comment: Beautiful! :-) Thanks!

Comment: I already did it :-) Otherwise I try same condition *ngif for minlenght for password, but f.password.errors.minlenght doesnt work. Any idea please?

Comment: No , but when I free I'll look into that

Comment: <div *ngIf="!!f.password.errors.minLength(6)">Password is too short!</div>

I tried something like this, but doesn´t work.
Of course,thank you :)